# /sys/bus/pci/devices/<B:D:F:>/rescan file missing on Ubuntu Kernel 5.4.14.050414-generic

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nvm, pci, pci-e, nvme

On my ubuntu I am missing rescan files under `/sys/bus/pci/devices/<B:D:F:>/`
Does anyone know how to restore them? Can I simply copy them from `/sys/bus/pci/rescan` ?

1. Ubuntu : 16.04.6 LTS
2. Kernel: 5.4.14.050414-generic
3. NVMe driver version: 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kernel 5.4 and later:

- `rescan` in `/sys/.../<domain:bus:dev.fn>/` was renamed `dev_rescan` (for PCI devices)
- `rescan` in `/sys/.../pci_bus/<domain:bus>/` was renamed `bus_rescan`

This caused application breakage and there is a [proposed patch](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-pci/20200325151708.32612-1-skunberg.kelsey@gmail.com/) to revert the behaviour